# Java Selenium - An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Tags: java, selenium, invalidselectorexception

I wanted to create an method that I can reuse whenever there is a form/textbox on the page and check if it is existing by returning True/False. I created Fields() that I placed on the same Sele class But I am not sure why I am getting the error :

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

---

````
public boolean Fields(String field, String name) {
    boolean f;
     if (field.equals("textbox")){
            return f= driver.findElement(By.name("'+ name +'")).isDisplayed();
           
     }

     return false;

        }



```
`
````

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this line:

```
return f= driver.findElement(By.name("'+ name +'")).isDisplayed();
```

Use this:

```
return f= driver.findElement(By.name('"'+ name +'"')).isDisplayed();
```

Comment: Hey thanks! i am no longer getting the exception error but on "tf = driver.findElement(By.name('"'+ name +'"')).isDisplayed();"   the "driver" has this error java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 driver cannot be resolved

Comment: If it works, accept this as the answer